# Detecting Blocked Threads

Tags: asynchronous, ccr, blocked-threads

I have a theory regarding trouble shooting a Asynchronous Application (I'm using the CCR) and I wonder if someone can confirm my logic.

If a CCR based multi-threaded application using the default number of threads (i.e. one per core) is slower than the same application with double the threads specified - does this means that threads are being blocked somewhere in the code

What do think?  Is this a quick and valid way to detect if threads are being inadvertantly being blocked?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "slower"?

If you want to automatically detect blocked threads, perhaps those threads should send a heartbeat, which are then observed by a monitor of some sort, but your options are limited.

Answer (score 0):

A cheap way to tell if threads are being blocked is to get the current system time before doing any potentially blocking operation, then after the operation, and see how much time has elapsed.  For example, while waiting for a message to arrive, measure to see how much time the thread was blocked waiting for a message to arrive.

Unless there are always more than enough messages to be processed, threads will block waiting for a message.  If you have more threads, then you have more potential message *generators* (depending on your design) and thus threads waiting to receive messages will be more likely to have one ready.

Exactly one thread to CPU is too few unless you can guarantee that there will always be enough messages so no thread will have to wait.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the case, that means that your threadpool is being exhausted (i.e. you have 2 threads but you've async pended 4 IOs or something) - if your work is heavily IO bound, the rule of "one thread per core" doesn't really apply.

Comment: Yes i am doing IO operations (Web services and SQL DB Calls)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that to keep the system fluid with minimal threads, I keep the tasks dealing with I/O as concise as possible. They simply post the data from the I/O into another Port and do no further processing. The data is therefore queued elsewhere for processing in a controlled manner without interfering with the task of grabbing data as fast as possible. This processing might happen in the ExclusiveGroup of an Interleave if there's shared state to think about... and a handy side-effect is that exclusive tasks will never tie up all the threads in a Dispatcher (however, I suspect that there's probably nattier ways of managing this in the CCR API)